# Remove redundant space at bottom when using Angular Flex with "row wrap" and grid-gap

Tags: html, css, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I'm using Angular Flex to align cards in a row. The cards should wrap into a new line if there are several of them. The relevant settings of the block are

```
fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="40px grid"
```

fxLayoutGap uses paddings on the inner elements and a negative margin on the container so that the gap is also applied when the inner elements wrap to a new row. So I do not want to remove the `grid` setting (or the paddings or negative margins in the

In addition, the cards are grouped into blocks with a header and a line on the left. I've created a sample that mirrors the settings that Angular Flex applies. The image is taken from this sample:

[image: Blocks with redundant space at the bottom]

As you can see, there is redundant space at the bottom of each group. I want the block and the line on the left to end where the last row of cards (of the block) ends:

[image: Blocks without redundant space at the bottom]

You can find the sample on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4roLw7ey/35/).

How can I adjust the CSS and/or the Angular Flex settings to remove the redundant space and make the line end at the last row of cards while preserving the space between the blocks?

Comment: FYI, you have many elements with the same ID value. This is invalid HTML (IDs must be unique) and can cause problems with script behavior. You should be using reusable classes (sets of like elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `padding-bottom` from the last two elements:

```css
#outer {
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#outer:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 40px; 
}

#header {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px 0px 40px 0px;
  background-color: red;
}

#container {
  margin: 40px -40px -40px 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#inner {
  padding: 0px 40px 40px 0px;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 50%;
  min-width: 50%;
}
/* added */
#inner:last-child,
#inner:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(odd){
   padding-bottom:0;
}
/**/

#card {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="inner">
      <div id="card">
        CARD
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="inner">
      <div id="card">
        CARD
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="inner">
      <div id="card">
        CARD
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="inner">
      <div id="card">
        CARD
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
<div id="outer">
  <div id="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="inner">
      <div id="card">
        CARD
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="inner">
      <div id="card">
        CARD
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>


<div id="outer">
  <div id="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="inner">
      <div id="card">
        CARD
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>

<div id="outer">
  <div id="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="inner">
      <div id="card">
        CARD
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="inner">
      <div id="card">
        CARD
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="inner">
      <div id="card">
        CARD
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works well for 2 items per row. Depending on the media size, I sometimes have 5, 3, 2 or 1 item per line. Is there an approach that works for any number of items per row or do I need to set up the CSS pseudo classes acording to media size?

Comment: Again, thank you very much. It was easy to create the CSS for the other media sizes. It seems, I can omit the `:nth-child(odd)` part because even if the style is applied to some items in a row, the remaining ones make sure that the gap is displayed.